# "what's needed more" or "what's more needed"?

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the correct form?

> what's needed **more**?
>
> what's **more** needed?

There is no context. It's generally used.

Comment: I think the usual way to ask this is not with "more" but with "else", "what else is needed?"  When you have "more", you probably have two things or entities you are comparing, like "what's more needed, {this} or {that}?"

Comment: Victor Bazarov is right that if you are asking if something more is needed, then it would be usual to say "What else is needed?"  If you are comparing two things, then you might say, "Which is needed more, X or Y?"
But there is also a common phrasing "What more is needed?" meaning, "What else do we have to do?"  Here's an example:
[Telemedicine: what more is needed for its integration in everyday life?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22208714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to have to say...neither.

> What's needed more?
>
> What's more needed?

I agree with Victor and stangdon. If you are trying to sound more like an English speaker, we would say (for example), "Which do we need more - a new car or more money in our savings account?

Used in another way, we could say, "We have gathered our supplies:  screwdriver, screws, drill, paint, brushes...  What *else* do we need?"

One more way is to be silly or sarcastic..."You have me.  What more do you need!"

I hope this helps!